# Core Data basics

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

Need help again! At application start I need to create 2 Entity: Provider и Country. I feel them like this:

```
-(NSArray *) resultArray {

    Provider *orangeFR = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    orangeFR.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Orange"];
    orangeFR.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Champ De Mars"];
    Provider *sfrFR = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    sfrFR.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SFR"];
    sfrFR.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SFR Adress"];
    NSArray *FRProviders = @[orangeFR, sfrFR];

    Provider *BeelineRU = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    BeelineRU.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beeline"];
    BeelineRU.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beeline adress"];
    Provider *MTSRU = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Provider" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    MTSRU.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MTS"];
    MTSRU.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MTS Adress"];
    NSArray *RUProviders = @[BeelineRU, MTSRU];

    Country *france = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    france.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"France"];
    [france addProvider:[NSSet setWithArray:FRProviders]];

    Country *russia = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    russia.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Russia"];
    [russia addProvider:[NSSet setWithArray:RUProviders]];

    NSArray *countries = @[france, russia];
    return countries;

}
```

How then I can use this data at next launch without creating them again? How can I count Country objects? What is the right method of passing Provider to next controller and how can I count then Provider in that controller?

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MSTProviderViewController *providerViewController = [[MSTProviderViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:providerViewController animated:YES];

    NSArray *countries = [self resultArray];
    Country *selectedCountry = countries[indexPath.row];
    Provider *selectedProvider = selectedCountry.provider; //[selectedCountry valueForKey:@"provider"];
    //NSArray *selectedProvider = [selectedCountry valueForKey:@"provider"];
    providerViewController.providers = selectedProvider;

}
```

Comment: This is at least four questions. Please edit it down to just the one, or it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @jrturton tell me please about initialisation and counting

Comment: Also try accepting answers to your previous questions if they helped. People spent time trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How then I can use this data at next launch without creating them again?

Fetch it from the Core Data store. For example using [NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008284-SW1).

> How can I count Country objects?

```
NSArray *resultArray = [self resultArray];
NSInteger count = [resultArray count];
```

> What is the right method of passing Provider to next controller and how can I count then Provider in that controller?

In the method which creates the next controller call

```
nextController.providerArray = self.providerArray;
```

If this doesn't help you, try to improve your question.